# Flutter visual keyboard show/hide on TextField of device_preview in Android Studio

Tags: android, flutter, web

In device_preview mode, I want to show the virtual keyboard when I tap on a text field and hide the keyboard when I click outside the text field area. How should I do this? Here is my code and demo:

Code:

1. main.dart

```
import 'package:device_preview/device_preview.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_keyboard_visibility/flutter_keyboard_visibility.dart';

import 'pages/home_page.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    DevicePreview(
      enabled: !kReleaseMode,
      builder: (context) => const MyApp(), // Wrap your app
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return KeyboardDismissOnTap(
      dismissOnCapturedTaps: false,
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        useInheritedMediaQuery: true,
        locale: DevicePreview.locale(context),
        builder: DevicePreview.appBuilder,
        darkTheme: ThemeData.dark(),
        title: 'ToDoList',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: const HomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

2. home_page.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import '../widgets/card_body_widget.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _HomePageState();
  }
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final FocusNode _focusNode = FocusNode();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build

    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () =>FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_focusNode),
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          title: const Text('ToDoList',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 40,
              )),
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(31),
          child: Column(
            children: const [
              CardBody(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            showModalBottomSheet(
              context: context,
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  height: 200,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                         const TextField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                          labelText: 'Your task',
                        ),
                      ),

                      const SizedBox(
                       height: 20,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: double.infinity,
                        height: 50,
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: (){},
                          child: const Text('Add Task'),
                        ),
                      ),

                  ]


                ),
                );
              },
            );
          },
          child: const Icon(Icons.add, size: 40),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Demo:[TodolistDemo](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1baJQ283t1pPOsCOOPCJY5VlLAzz9P3VS/view?usp=sharing)

I have imported 'package:flutter_keyboard_visibility/flutter_keyboard_visibility.dart'; and tried to use the KeyboardDismissOnTap widget like this:

```
KeyboardDismissOnTap(
  dismissOnCapturedTaps: false,
  child: [Code is here],
)
```

but the keyboard is not dismissed when I tap outside the textfield area.

Furthermore, I added

```
final FocusNode _focusNode = FocusNode();
GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_focusNode),
      child: [Code is here])
```

to show the virtual keyboard when I tapped on the text field, but it didn't work.

In addition, in device_preview mode, there is a virtual keyboard button, when I click show, the virtual keyboard will always be displayed even if I don't click on the text field, and it won't hide when I click elsewhere. What should I do now?

Answer (score 0):

I try to help with your problem.

You could try this solution, using **FocusScope** approach.

```
      ///code
     late final TextEditingController _textController;
     late final FocusNode _focusNode;
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        _textController = TextEditingController();
        _focusNode = FocusNode();
      }
    
      @override
        void dispose() {
          _textController.dispose();
          _focusNode.dispose();
           super.dispose();
        }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: const Text(
          'ToDoList',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 40,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: FocusScope(
        node: _focusNode,
        child: GestureDetector(
          onTap: () => _focusNode.unfocus(),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(31),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                TextField(
                  controller: _textController,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
                    labelText: 'Your task',
                  ),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                const CardBody(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

so, what I try to do here is to wrap the body with **FocusScope** and then assign _focusNode that I have initialized before, now you could control the keyboard button, by using onTap: () => _focusNode.unfocus() to dismiss the keyboard.

Comment: I still encounter the same error after following your suggestion. 
Code home_page.dart:
//code
child: FocusScope(
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () => _focusNode.unfocus(),
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                      child: Column(children: [
                        const TextField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
 labelText: 'Your task', ),

Comment: so It does not dismiss the keyboard? because what I did above is trying to dismiss the keyboard whenever you touch around the SingleChildScrollView and its descendent or do you want to show the keyboard actually? if so simply add TextField(
   onTap: () => _focusNode.requestFocus(),
  )

Comment: I want the keyboard in device_preview to only appear when I click on any text field, here specifically the one with the label text 'your task' in the showModalBottomSheet. Therefore, the default state of the keyboard in device_preview should be hidden.

Comment: "Have you seen the demo? As you can see, when I click on the 'visible' button in the virtual keyboard preview, the virtual keyboard will always appear and there is no way to close it. What I want is that the virtual keyboard preview should only be visible when I click on a textfield, and if I click anywhere outside the textfield, the virtual keyboard preview should return to the hidden state.

Comment: I have also tried requestFocus and unFocus but it seems like they do not affect the state of the virtual keyboard preview (hidden/visible) in device_preview